# Rails 4: form_for with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to rails and ruby. Struggling with `form_for` and associations. I am trying  to setup a rails app that allows a user to select from a list of clients. The clients are associated via `has_many :through` relationships. I have the models working as expected and I can add clients to users via the rails console. I now want to move this capability to the web interface. The below code is how I have tried, but it is just not making sense to me. I am unsure which controller action is the correct action. Should I process the form `POST` in the create action of the client? I am not actually wanting to create a new client, I just want the user to select from a list of existing clients and create the association.

My Models are as follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users, :through => :user_clients
has_many :user_clients, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :clients, :through => :user_clients
has_many :user_clients, :dependent => :destroy
end

class UserClient < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :client
end
```

Routes as follows

```
resources :clients do
  resources :users
end

resources :users do
  resources :clients
end
```

Clients Controllers

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:user_id]
      @clients = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).clients
    else
      @clients = Client.all
    end
    @clients
  end

  def create
    if params[:user_id]
      user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      client = Client.find_by_id(params[:client_id])
      user.clients << client
      user.save
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      @client = Client.new(client_params)
      @client.save
      redirect_to clients_url
    end
  end
end
```

Form in the client view

```
<h1>new.html.erb</h1>
<% if params[:user_id] %>
  <%= form_for([@user,@client]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at that gem: [Nested Form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). Here's also a couple of [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested%20form) on the topic. However, if you're willing to build your own solution, you can start by reading documentation on nested attributes [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Hope it helps!

***Update***. About your routes and everything.

```
resources :clients do
  resources :users
end

resources :users do
  resources :clients
end
```

You've nested resources here. Like you mentioned in your comment, `users/:user_id/clients/new` and `clients/new` will lead to the same action. That's the way this routing works. You're correct about *Rails style of doing things* - that's pretty bad to make some scary logic checks in controller and do, basically, **different things inside of one action**. Since your action (associating user with existing client) is quite far from a standard set of RESTful actions (the closest variant will be `update` though), you need to introduce new action for your resource - for example `assign_client`. You can do it like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :clients
  member do
    put :assign_client
  end
end
```

You can render form in any action you like. However, if you want something more *standalone* you can create a pair of actions (something like `edit` and `update` pair). The first one will render an appropriate form and the second one will process that form on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still trying to understand how to manage adding a new client association to a user. In my above example the route /clients/new and the route /users/1/clients/new both get routed to the clients controller 'create' method. However, I would like /clients/new to be used to create a new client record and /users/1/clients/new to create a new association between a user and an existing client. I could test for this in the 'create' method, however I am unsure if this is the 'rails' convention for this type of activity.