# RoR: How to populate table from radio buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button

In my application I have a form with radio buttons:

```
<%= form_for @homework.homework_students.homework_ratings do |f| %>
  <label>
    <%= f.radio_button :fb_value, '1', :fb_type, 'Difficulty' %>
  </label>
  1
  <label>
    <%= f.radio_button :fb_value, '2', :fb_type, 'Difficulty' %>
  </label>
  2
  <label>
    <%= f.radio_button :fb_value, '3', :fb_type, 'Difficulty' %>
    3
  </label>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The aim is to populate two columns (called "value" and "type") for each homework in a table (not sure if syntax is correct above) called "homework_ratings" which is associated with a table called "homework_students":

homework_ratings.rb

```
belongs_to :homework_student, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent', :foreign_key => :homework_student_id
```

homework_students.rb

```
 has_many :homework_ratings, :class_name => 'HomeworkRating'
    belongs_to :homework, :class_name => 'Homework', :foreign_key =>        :homework_id, dependent: :destroy
```

homework_students has many homeworks:

homework.rb

```
has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent', dependent: :destroy
```

homework_ratings table:

```
id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  homework_student_id :integer
#  type                :integer
#  value               :string(255)
#  created_at          :datetime         not null
#  updated_at          :datetime         not null
```

homeworks_controller.rb

```
def show
        @homework_ratings = HomeworkRating.all
...
end
```

In a nutshell i'm trying to populate a table from homeworks that has no direct association with homework but is indirectly associated as above through homework_students.

I get the error "undefined method homework_ratings" on trying to load page.

Any thoughts as to how best to approach this?

Thanks, can provide more info...

Comment: this isn't the answer, but, i'd use something other than `value` and `type` for field names, because those will inevitably clash with inbuilt rails methods.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify. You're trying to record a rating for a piece of homework, right? so you create a dedicated ratings controller, and you just create a rating. Always try to make a resource out of something you're creating. You should have a lot of resources/controllers in your app.

```
<%= form_for @homework_rating do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :homework_student_id %>
```

in the controller:

```
def new
  @homework_student = HomeworkStudent.find params[:homework_student_id]
  @homework_rating = @homework.ratings.new
end
```

you probably also want to look as `has_many :through`

edit: you can't set two values with one radio button. but you can create a writer method in the ratings model

```
def set_values=(val)
  self.type = "foo"
  self.value = "bar"
end
```

you can then do all sorts of ruby on the val, like if or case. you'd need to come up with a way of communicating that between the radio buttons and the model action.

Comment: Thanks, I did your suggestion, but get this error:  "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". I am loading the show view in homework.

Comment: I'm trying something based on your guidance. I think my syntax is wrong in form for radio button though wrong number of arguments (4 for 2..3) - this is on the first radio button...

Comment: Yes, because you need to set up the instance variable @homework_rating in whatever action you're rendering the form, in your case it's show not new.

Comment: Thanks, is that in homework_controller? I'm doing that but get this error Couldn't find HomeworkStudent with 'id'=

Comment: I think you need to do some less complex rails concepts until you understand where all the pieces go and how do to associations and forms. Otherwise this is going to devolve into a back-and-forth chat :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729684/rails-4-form-for-with-associations might help you along with the linked rails casts